# How do i assign element in a list to another element in a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, variable-assignment

I have a list of different emails and a list of pre-generated promo codes. I'm trying to assign each email to a different promo code. I need this proccess to occur on a daily basis so I never assign a promo code twice.

```
emails = [email1, email2, email3,...]  

p_codes = [pcodes1, pcodes2, pcodes3,...]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: So, what do you want your resulting data structure to look like? Is it safe to assume that email1 ties to pcodes1...?

Comment: your question is not clear! but you can use dict and assign emails to each pcodes as you want.

Comment: Why do you need a pre-generated list of codes? Why not just generate a new one for each email?

Comment: @Ben emails don´t connect to any p_codes. I just need to assign a different p_codes to each email and every day i have a new list a new list of emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can combine lists using zip:

```
emails = [email1, email2, email3,...]  
p_codes = [pcodes1, pcodes2, pcodes3,...]
combined_emails_codes = list(zip(emails, p_codes))
# [(email1, pcodes1), (email2, pcodes2) ....]
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, how do i block previously sent pcodes?

Comment: How do you generate pcodes?

Comment: I have a list of millions of pcodes and every day i have a new list of emails. I need to assign pcodes to these emails, but i can't send a pcode twice.

Comment: then just add those to a list of used_pcodes and skip those in the future

Comment: Nathan i think it would solve. I will combine the lists and generate a used_pcodes with the ones i already assigned! Thank you